# Date in SQL Pivot to be transformed from yyyy-mm-dd to mm-yy

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, pivot

I have a pivot query IN SQL Server 2016 that works somewhat good:

```
select *

FROM (select Analyst,Task_Type,Load,Completed,Date_Of_Assignment

 from mytable where Task_Type IN ('Loans') ) as TEST PIVOT 

(

SUM(Completed)

FOR 

[Date_Of_Assignment] IN ([2018-05-22],[2018-06-22],[2018-07-22])

) as P
```

it returns as:

```
Agent_Name  Task_Type   Total_Received  2018-05-22  2018-06-22 2018-07-22
Steve       Loans        20                 15         15           15
Cathe       Loans        20                 15         15           15
Adam        Loans        20                 15         15           15
Klaus       Loans        20                 15         15           15
```

which is cool, but I need it more like this

```
Agent_Name  Task_Type   Total_Received    May 18     June 18      July 18
Steve       Loans        20                 15         15           15
Cathe       Loans        20                 15         15           15
Adam        Loans        20                 15         15           15
Klaus       Loans        20                 15         15           15
```

Considering that it might be more than one day of data per Load, actually it should be every workday.

I tried by grouping by Date_ but it returns errors.

If I do like:

```
select *

FROM (select Analyst,Task_Type,Load,Completed,Date_Of_Assigment

CASE WHEN FORMAT(Date_Of_Assigment,'MM-yy') = '05-18' THEN 'May 18'
     WHEN FORMAT(Date_Of_Assigment,'MM-yy') = '06-18' THEN 'Jun 18'
     WHEN FORMAT(Date_Of_Assigment,'MM-yy') = '07-18' THEN 'Jul 18'
END AS MonthT

 from mytable where Task_Type IN ('Loans') as TEST PIVOT 


(

SUM(Completed)

FOR 

[MonthT] IN (['May 18'],['Jun 18'],['Jul 18'])

) as P
```

I receive:

```
Analyst    Task     Total_Received   'May 18'   'Jun 18'    'Jul 18'
Steve     Billing     20                NULL       NULL       NULL
Cathe     Billing     20                NULL       NULL       NULL
Adam      Billing     20                NULL       NULL       NULL
Klaus     Billing     20                NULL       NULL       NULL
```

It does turn Dates into columns but with NULLS only.

Data types are: Date for Date_Of_Assigment, nvarchar for Task_Type and Analyst and integer for the rest of columns.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I would do this as :

```
select Analyst, Task, 
       sum(case when MonthT = '05-18' then Completed else 0 end) [May 18],
       sum(case when MonthT = '06 18' then Completed else 0 end) [Jun 18],
       sum(case when MonthT = '05-18' then Completed else 0 end) [Jul 18]
from table t cross apply
     ( values format (Date_Of_Assigment, 'MM-yy')
     ) tt (MonthT)
where Task_Type = 'Loans'
group by Analyst, Task;
```

Comment: Hello all! Thank you for your help, I removed the quotes in:                                                 [MonthT] IN (['May 18'],['Jun 18'],['Jul 18']) and now it´s working greatly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM ( 

    SELECT 
        Analyst
        , Task_Type
        , [Load]
        , Completed
        , DATENAME( MM, Date_Of_Assignment )  + ' ' + CAST( ( YEAR( Date_Of_Assignment ) % 100 ) AS VARCHAR(2) ) AS Date_Of_Assignment
    FROM mytable WHERE Task_Type IN ( 'Loans' ) 

) AS TEST
PIVOT (

    SUM(Completed)
    FOR 
    [Date_Of_Assignment] IN ( [May 18], [June 18], [July 18] )

) AS P
```

I don't have access to your data to test this, but in theory, it should do what you're looking for.

Here's a simple proof of concept you can run in SSMS:

```
DECLARE @mytable TABLE (
    Analyst VARCHAR(10), Task_Type VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'Loans', [Load] INT, Completed INT, Date_Of_Assignment DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @mytable ( Analyst, [Load], Completed, Date_Of_Assignment )
VALUES
( 'Steve', 3, 2, '05/22/2018' )
, ( 'Steve', 1, 1, '06/22/2018' )
, ( 'Steve', 4, 3, '07/22/2018' );

SELECT 
    Analyst, Task_Type, SUM( [Load] ) AS Total_Recieved, SUM( [May 18] ) AS [May 18], SUM( [June 18] ) AS [June 18], SUM( [July 18] ) AS [July 18]
FROM ( 

    SELECT 
        Analyst
        , Task_Type
        , [Load]
        , Completed
        , DATENAME( MM, Date_Of_Assignment )  + ' ' + CAST( ( YEAR( Date_Of_Assignment ) % 100 ) AS VARCHAR(2) ) AS Date_Of_Assignment
    FROM @mytable 
    WHERE Task_Type IN ( 'Loans' )

) AS TEST
PIVOT (

    SUM( Completed ) FOR [Date_Of_Assignment] IN ( [May 18], [June 18], [July 18] )

) AS P
GROUP BY Analyst, Task_Type;
```

Returns

```
+---------+-----------+----------------+--------+---------+---------+
| Analyst | Task_Type | Total_Recieved | May 18 | June 18 | July 18 |
+---------+-----------+----------------+--------+---------+---------+
| Steve   | Loans     |              8 |      2 |       1 |       3 |
+---------+-----------+----------------+--------+---------+---------+
```